# Best practice to run Linux service as a different user

Tags: linux, system-administration, rhel, init.d

Services default to starting as `root` at boot time on my RHEL box. If I recall correctly, the same is true for other Linux distros which use the init scripts in `/etc/init.d`.

What do you think is the best way to instead have the processes run as a (static) user of my choosing?

The only method I'd arrived at was to use something like:

```
 su my_user -c 'daemon my_cmd &>/dev/null &'
```

But this seems a bit untidy...

Is there some bit of magic tucked away that provides an easy mechanism to automatically start services as other, non-root users?

**EDIT:** I should have said that the processes I'm starting in this instance are either Python scripts or Java programs. I'd rather not write a native wrapper around them, so unfortunately I'm unable to call [setuid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid) as [Black](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25234/black) suggests.

Comment: Does Python not provide access to the setuid() family of system calls?  That seems like a serious defect in comparison with Perl.

Comment: Wow, yes it does: os.setuid(uid). Every day's a school day!

Answer (score 68, accepted):

On Debian we use the `start-stop-daemon` utility, which handles pid-files, changing the user, putting the daemon into background and much more.

I'm not familiar with RedHat, but the `daemon` utility that you are already using (which is defined in `/etc/init.d/functions`, btw.) is mentioned everywhere as the equivalent to `start-stop-daemon`, so either it can also change the uid of your program, or the way you do it is already the correct one.

If you look around the net, there are several ready-made wrappers that you can use. Some may even be already packaged in RedHat. Have a look at [`daemonize`](http://www.clapper.org/software/daemonize/), for example.

Comment: The x-ref is interesting.  I have my own daemonize program, very similar; doesn't do the pidfile or lockfile, does set umask. I have a separate SUID root program for setting UID, GID, EUID, EGID, and aux groups (called asroot). I use 'asroot [opts] -- env -i [env] daemonize [opts] -- command [opts]'

Comment: (continued): the POSIX standard env program does not accept '--' between the environment setting and the executed command (irksome, but so).

Comment: How can daemon function from /etc/init.d/functions be used in upstart script? Can you show an example, please.

Comment: On Debian see `/etc/init.d/skeleton`. Add UID, GID variables and in`do_start()` use: `start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --chuid $UID:$GID -- $DAEMON_ARGS`

Comment: I notice `daemon()` is defined in `/etc/rc.d/init.d/function` on both RHEL & CentOS boxs of mine.

Answer (score 53):

After looking at all the suggestions here, I've discovered a few things which I hope will be useful to others in my position:

1. [hop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3850/hop) is right to point me back
   at `/etc/init.d/functions`: the
   `daemon` function already allows you
   to set an alternate user:

   ```
   daemon --user=my_user my_cmd &>/dev/null &
   ```

   This is implemented by wrapping the
   process invocation with `runuser` -
   more on this later.
2. [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) is right:
   there is setuid in Python:

   ```
   import os
   os.setuid(501) # UID of my_user is 501
   ```

   I still don't think you can setuid
   from inside a JVM, however.
3. Neither `su` nor `runuser`
   gracefully handle the case where you
   ask to run a command as the user you
   already are. E.g.:

   ```
   [my_user@my_host]$ id
   uid=500(my_user) gid=500(my_user) groups=500(my_user)
   [my_user@my_host]$ su my_user -c "id"
   Password: # don't want to be prompted!
   uid=500(my_user) gid=500(my_user) groups=500(my_user)
   ```

To workaround that behaviour of `su` and `runuser`, I've changed my init script to something like:

```
if [[ "$USER" == "my_user" ]]
then
    daemon my_cmd &>/dev/null &
else
    daemon --user=my_user my_cmd &>/dev/null &
fi
```

Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 5):

- Some daemons (e.g. apache) do this by themselves by calling [setuid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid)
- You could use the [setuid-file flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) to run the process as a different user.
- Of course, the solution you mentioned works as well.

If you intend to write your own daemon, then I recommend calling setuid().
This way, your process can

1. Make use of its root privileges (e.g. open log files, create pid files).
2. Drop its root privileges at a certain point during startup.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add some other things to watch out for:

- Sudo in a init.d script is no good since it needs a tty ("sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo")
- If you are daemonizing a java application, you might want to consider Java Service Wrapper (which provides a mechanism for setting the user id)
- Another alternative could be *su --session-command=[cmd] [user]*

Answer (score 3):

on a CENTOS (Red Hat) virtual machine for svn server:
edited `/etc/init.d/svnserver`
to change the pid to something that svn can write:

```
pidfile=${PIDFILE-/home/svn/run/svnserve.pid}
```

and added option `--user=svn`:

```
daemon --pidfile=${pidfile} --user=svn $exec $args
```

The original pidfile was `/var/run/svnserve.pid`.  The daemon did not start becaseu only root could write there.

```
 These all work:
/etc/init.d/svnserve start
/etc/init.d/svnserve stop
/etc/init.d/svnserve restart
```

Comment: This creates a privilege escalation vulnerability. The svn user can now put arbitrary PIDs in the /home/svn/run/svnserve.pid file which will be killed instead of the svn process whenever the svn service is stopped or restarted.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to watch out for:

- As you mentioned, su will prompt for a password if you are already the target user
- Similarly, setuid(2) will fail if you are already the target user (on some OSs)
- setuid(2) does not install privileges or resource controls defined in /etc/limits.conf (Linux) or /etc/user_attr (Solaris)
- If you go the setgid(2)/setuid(2) route, don't forget to call initgroups(3) -- more on this  [here](http://daemons.net/~clay/2009/05/02/setuid-ate-my-css/)

I generally use /sbin/su to switch to the appropriate user before starting daemons.

Answer (score 2):

Why not try the following in the init script:

```
setuid $USER application_name
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This isn't available on all distros. I tried on RHEL 7: `setuid: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run a Spring .jar application as a service, and found a simple way to run this as a specific user:

I changed the owner and group of my jar file to the user I wanted to run as.
Then symlinked this jar in init.d and started the service.

So:

```
#chown myuser:myuser /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/springApp/target/springApp-1.0.jar

#ln -s /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/springApp/target/springApp-1.0.jar /etc/init.d/springApp

#service springApp start

#ps aux | grep java
myuser    9970  5.0  9.9 4071348 386132 ?      Sl   09:38   0:21 /bin/java -Dsun.misc.URLClassPath.disableJarChecking=true -jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/springApp/target/springApp-1.0.jar
```