# Running a program as non root from a script

Tags: linux

I have a question closely related to this thread:
[Best practice to run Linux service as a different user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394984/best-practice-to-run-linux-service-as-a-different-user)

but I need the solution to work in "every" Linux distribution.

I would like to run a program as a non root user from a script. This way, when init.d starts up the services at boot time as root, the script launches the process as the non-root user I specify. Of course the solution shouldn't prompt for a password.

I think this is the normal/correct procedure when deploying applications.

How could I do that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

A good way would be to drop privileges from your actual program. Then just pass that user as a parameter. Inside you can handle it in a very standard way (`setuid()`)

Otherwise `su -c 'your command' different_user` will work just fine on any linux. (as long as different_user exists)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

1. `sudo` command - you need to add the original user to `/etc/sudoers` with such entry that the **program** can be run without (`NOPASSWD`)
2. `seteuid()` system call (if you can modify the program)

If you are `root`, you can also use `su` (see @cnicutar's answer for details)