# uWSGI works as process but not as daemon

Tags: flask, ubuntu-12.04, uwsgi

For my current flask deployment, I had to set up a uwsgi server.
This is how I have created the uwsgi daemon:

`sudo vim /etc/init/uwsgi.conf`

```
# file: /etc/init/uwsgi.conf
description "uWSGI server"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn

exec /myproject/myproject-env/bin/uwsgi --uid www-data --gid www-data --home /myproject/myproject-env/site/F11/Engineering/  --socket /tmp/uwsgi.sock --chmod-socket --module F11 --callable app --pythonpath /myproject/myproject-env/site/F11/Engineering/ -H /myproject/myproject-env
```

However after running this successfully: `sudo start uwsgi`

```
uwsgi start/running, process 1286
```

And trying to access the application via browser:

I get a **502 Bad Gateway**

and an error entry in nginx error.log:

> 2013/06/13 23:47:28 [error] 743#0: *296 upstream prematurely closed
>   connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
>   xx.161.xx.228, server: myproject.com, request: "GET /show_records/2013/6 HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock:", host: "myproject.com"

But the sock file has the permission it needs:

```
srw-rw-rw- 1 www-data www-data 0 Jun 13 23:46 /tmp/uwsgi.sock
```

If I run the `exec` command from above in the command line as a process, it works perfectly fine.  Why is the daemon not working correctly please?

btw Nginx is running as 
`vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;
```

and `vim /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
location / {
                uwsgi_pass   unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
                include        uwsgi_params;
        }
```

and it is started as `sudo service nginx start`

I am running this on `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`.

I hope I have provided all the necessary data, hope someone can guide me into the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Do you use debian or ubuntu?

Comment: @joe, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS that is. I just tested it on my laptop running 13.04 and its exactly the same problem. Which is good, hence replicable.

Comment: sounds like the daemon runs under a different user or has access to different configs... isn't this a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394984/best-practice-to-run-linux-service-as-a-different-user

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally I have solved this problem after working nearly 2 days on it. I hope this solution will help other flask/uwsgi users that are experiencing a similar problem.

I had two major issues that caused this.

1) The best way to find the problems with a daemon is obviously a log file and a cleaner structure.

`sudo vim /etc/init/uwsgi.conf`

Change the daemon script to the following:

```
# file: /etc/init/uwsgi.conf
description "uWSGI server"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]
respawn
exec /home/ubuntu/uwsgi-1.9.12/uwsgi -c /myproject/uwsgi.ini
```

`vim /myproject/uwsgi.ini`

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
master = true
enable-threads = true
processes = 5
chdir= /myproject/F11/Engineering
module=F11:app
virtualenv = /myproject/myproject-env/
uid =  www-data
gid = www-data
logto = /myproject/error.log
```

This is much cleaner way of setting up the daemon. Also notice the last line how to setup the log file.  Initially I had set the log file to `/var/log/uwsgi/error.log`.  After a lot of sweat and tears I realized the daemon is running as `www-data` and hence can not access the `/var/log/uwsgi/error.log` since the error.log was owned by `root:root`. This made the uwsgi fail silently.

I found it much more efficient to just point the log file to my own `/myproject`, where the daemon has guaranteed access as `www-data`.  And also don't forget to make the whole project accessible to `www-data` or the daemon will fail with an `Internal Server error message`. -->

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /myproject/
```

Restart uwsgi daemon:

```
sudo service uwsgi restart
```

2) Now you have three log files to lookout for:

- `tail -f /var/log/upstart/uwsgi.log`  --> Shows problems with your daemon upon start
- `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log`  --> Shows permission problems when wsgi access is refused, often because `/tmp/uwsgi.sock` file is owned by `root` instead of `www-data`. In that case simply delete the sock file `sudo rm /tmp/uwsgi.sock`
- `tail -f /myproject/error.log`  --> Shows errors thrown by uwsgi in your application

This combination of log files helped me to figure out that I also had a bad import with Flask-Babel in my Flask application.  Bad in that sense, that the way I utilized the library was falling back to the system's locale to determine the datetime format.

```
File "/myproject/F11/Engineering/f11_app/templates/show_records.html", line 25, in block "body"
    <td>{{ record.record_date|format_date }}</td>
  File "./f11_app/filters.py", line 7, in format_date
    day = babel_dates.format_date(value, "EE")
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/babel/dates.py", line 459, in format_date
    return pattern.apply(date, locale)
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/babel/dates.py", line 702, in apply
    return self % DateTimeFormat(datetime, locale)
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/babel/dates.py", line 699, in __mod__
    return self.format % other
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/babel/dates.py", line 734, in __getitem__
    return self.format_weekday(char, num)
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/babel/dates.py", line 821, in format_weekday
    return get_day_names(width, context, self.locale)[weekday]
  File "/myproject/myproject-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/babel/dates.py", line 69, in get_day_names
    return Locale.parse(locale).days[context][width]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'days'
```

This is the way I was using the Flask filter:

```
import babel.dates as babel_dates

@app.template_filter('format_date')
def format_date(value):
    day = babel_dates.format_date(value, "EE")
    return '{0} {1}'.format(day.upper(), affix(value.day))
```

The strangest part is that this code is working perfectly fine within the dev environment (!). It works even fine when running the uwsgi as a root process from the command line. But it fails when ran by the www-data daemon. This must have something to do with how the locale is set, which Flask-Babel is trying to fall back to.

When I changed the import like this, it all worked finally with the daemon:

```
from flask.ext.babel import format_date  

@app.template_filter('format_date1')
def format_date1(value):
    day = format_date(value, "EE")
    return '{0} {1}'.format(day.upper(), affix(value.day))
```

Hence be careful when using Eclipse/Aptana Studio that is trying to pick the right namespace for your classes in code. It can really turn ugly.

It is now working perfectly fine as a uwsgi daemon on an Amazon Ec2 (Ubuntu 12.04) since 2 days. I hope this experience helps fellow python developers.

Comment: Glad to know that you have solved the problem, however, I would recommend to use the following way: https://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/python-uwsgi/ubuntu-12.04-precise-pangolin . I have used it in many servers.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up, there was no uwsgi.log generated, and nginx just kept complaining about :

```
2014/03/06 01:06:28 [error] 23175#0: *22 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: client.IP, server: my.server.IP, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/var/web/the_gelatospot/uwsgi.sock:", host: "host.ip"
```

for every single request. This only happened if running uwsgi as a service, as a process it started fine under any user. So this would work from command line (page responds):

```
$exec /var/web/the_gelatospot/mez_server.sh
```

This didn't (/etc/init/site_service.conf):

```
description "mez sites virtualenv and uwsgi_django" start on runlevel
[2345] stop on runlevel [06] respawn respawn limit 10 5 exec
/var/web/the_gelatospot/mez_server.sh
```

The process would start but on each request nginx would complain about the closed connection. Strangely I have this same config working just fine for 2 other apps using the same nginx version and same uwsgi version as well as both apps are mezzanine CMS apps. I tried everything I could think of and what was suggested. In the end I switched to gunicorn which works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="the_gelatospot"                                          # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/var/web/the_gelatospot              # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/var/web/the_gelatospot/gunicorn.sock     # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=ec2-user
GROUP=ec2-user                                             # the user to run as, the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
#DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=the_gelatospot.settings             # which settings file should Django use
#DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=the_gelatospot.wsgi                   # WSGI module name
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=wsgi

echo "Starting $NAME as `the_gelatospot`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../mez_env/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR
cd ..
# Start your Django GUnicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec gunicorn -k eventlet ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --log-level=debug \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE
```

And here is the one that wouldn't work as a service (nginx complaining of prematurely closed connection and no app log data coming through).

```
#!/bin/bash

DJANGODIR=/var/web/the_gelatospot/                # Django project directory
cd $DJANGODIR
source ../mez_env/bin/activate
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

And the uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = 222
gid = 500
socket = /var/web/the_gelatospot/uwsgi.sock
virtualenv = /var/web/mez_env
chdir = /var/web/the_gelatospot/
wsgi-file = /var/web/the_gelatospot/wsgi.py
pythonpath = ..
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=the_gelatospot.settings
die-on-term = true
master = true
chmod-socket = 666
;experiment using uwsgitop
worker = 1
;gevent = 100
processes = 1
daemonize = /var/log/nginx/uwsgi.log
logto = /var/log/nginx/uwsgi.logi
log-maxsize = 10000000
enable-threads = true
```

I went from gunicorn to uWSGI last year and I had no issues with it till now, it also seemed a  bit faster than gunicorn.  Right now I'm thinking of sticking to gunicorn. Its getting better, puts up much nicer numbers with eventlet installed, and it is easier to configure.

Hope this workaround helps. I would still like to know the issue with uWSGI and nginx but I'm stumped.

**Update:** 
So using gunicorn allowed me to run the server as a service and while toying in mezzanine I ran into this error: FileSystemEncodingChanged

To fix this I found the solution here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mezzanine-users/bdln_Y99zQw/9HrhNSKFyZsJ

And I had to modify it a bit since I don't use supervisord, I only use upstart and a shell script. I added this to right before I execute gunicorn in my mez_server.sh file:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8, LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8, LC_LANG=en_US.UTF-8
exec gunicorn -k eventlet ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --log-level=debug \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE
```

I also tried this fix using uWSGI like so ( a lot shorter since using uwsgi.ini ):

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8, LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8, LC_LANG=en_US.UTF-8
exec uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

I am still sticking to gunicorn since it still worked with the problem and lead me in the right direction to resolve it. I was very disappointed that uWSGI provided no output in the log file even with these params, I only seen the server start process and that's it:

```
daemonize = /var/log/nginx/uwsgi.log
logto = /var/log/nginx/uwsgi.logi
```

While nginx kept throwing the disconnect error, uWSGI sat there like nothing is happening.

Comment: I am sorry my solution above didn't help you. I struggled with it also over a week. It can be very frustrating. It must be lacking privileges on some directories, which isn't easy to find. Gunicorn is much easier to setup, but it also takes 150 MB of memory. uWSGI has tiny memory footprint, but hard to setup.

Comment: I fixed it now, but still going to use gunicorn, it seemed to lead me in the right path to solve the issue. The issue for me was a locale problem, I had to set these variables in my task (mez_server.sh) that controls process startup: export LANG=en_US.UTF-8, LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8, LC_LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: You're right, uWSGI was taking .7% of memory (13-17MB), thats less than 1%, for the same task but I increased the workers from 1 to 3, each worker on gunicorn is about 3-7% (20-40MB), plus the master task is 2%. I really like using both and didn't find 1 harder to configure over the other. I'll stick to gunicorn unless I really need that memory footprint reduced. PS. vacuum parm for uwsgi didn't work for me, the zombie process stays running, what fixes it is this parm: die-on-term = true

Comment: After a long time I am setting up nginx and uwsgi on a new server.  I get now your uptream problem. Were you able to solve them before moving to Gunicorn?

Comment: I found the reason. I will add more details to my answer tomorrow.

Comment: When I switched back to gunicorn it told me what the error was, don't remember what it was, so long ago.

Answer (score -1):

As a single line running  with daemon true command is

```
gunicorn  app.wsgi:application -b 127.0.0.1:8000 --daemon
```

bind your app with 127.0.0.1:8000 and --deamon  force it to run as daemon

but define a gunicorn_config.cfg file and run with -c flag is good practice

for more:

https://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/develop/configure.html