# How to use supervisor fo start/stop uWSGI application?

Tags: uwsgi, supervisord

I use a supervisor to run uWSGI application. Why uWSGI application does not always stop after stop supervisor?
supervisor config:

```
[program:test]
autostart = true
user=root
command=uwsgi --master --workers  5 --disable-logging --socket 127.0.0.1:8888
--module web --callable app
priority=1
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile = /data/log
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

By default supervisor send SIGTERM on stop. SIGTERM in uWSGI means 'brutal reload'.

You have to change it to QUIT or INT:

stopsignal=QUIT

should be enough

Another approach (discouraged) is adding --die-on-term to uWSGI command line to change its default behaviour

Comment: why it's discouraged ?

Comment: Because you need this option only if you use supervisor. It is better to fix supervisor's behaviour in supervisor's config.

Comment: I have little experience with either method but when I was looking for the right config to use I found a few examples of problems that were apparently only solved by using `die-on-term` eg http://stackoverflow.com/a/22213404/202168 https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/issues/296

Answer (score 4):

1. project supervisor config file

   > add `stopsignal=INT`
2. project uwsgi config file

   > remove `daemonize=xxx.log` to disable daemon mode

Comment: Great tip. With daemonize on in uwsgi, when controlled via sword i found the OS would run of memory and produce this error: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

Answer (score 4):

If you use "processes = #" into your uwsgi configuration, you also must use "master = true". If not, supervisor only will kill one of workers.

Then:

/etc/supervisor/conf.d/app.conf

```
stopsignal = QUIT
```

/etc/uwsgi/app.ini

```
processes = 4
master = true
```

Comment: I used `stopsignal = QUIT` but after stopped it in supervisorctl, some new uwsgi processes was created by pid 1. `stopsignal=INT` does the stop thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your UWSGI with master and workers you need to add in your `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/app.conf` file

```
stopasgroup=false
killasgroup=false
```

or else no matter what stopping uwsgi will spawn more master and so is workers.

Comment: This is the default config. I could only make the `supervisorctl restart process` work correctly by setting both options to `true`.