# Where is the uWSGI (error) log file when installing uWSGI using pip?

Tags: django, nginx, pip, uwsgi

I'm trying to run my Django app using Nginx and uWSGI. When I try to go to

```
127.0.0.1:8001/media/media.png
```

Nginx properly shows the image, but when I go to

```
127.0.0.1:8000/CMS/users
```

Django is supposed to call a view. Instead, Nginx returns a 504 Gateway Time-out. When I view the Nginx error log, it says

```
*6 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 192.168.174.131, request: "GET /CMS/users HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:8001", host: "127.0.0.1:8000"
```

Does a uWSGI error log file exist? If yes, where can I find it? (I'm searching for it because I think it might help debug the issue).

Note: I installed uwsgi using pip.

Comment: Use `logto` or `daemonize` startup parameter to config log file path. You can refer to this answer for some tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099114/uwsgi-works-as-process-but-not-as-daemon/#17138212

Comment: How do you run your uWSGI? Try to use `logto`. http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Logging.html

Comment: logto does it, thanks. I run it like so: "uwsgi --http :8001 --module CMS.wsgi --logto /tmp/mylog.log". One of you can place it as the answer and I will accept it.